# Как монтировать раздел размонтированный ранее

Tags: c++

Я демонтирую область такими функциями:

```
DeviceIoControl(hDisk, FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

DeviceIoControl(hDisk, FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, 0, 0, 0, 0, &dwBytesWritten, 0);
```

После завершение программы раздел монтируется сам, но мне нужно делать это внутри программы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне монтировать его во время работы программы.

Comment: В описании кода `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME` сказано-же, что том можно обратно смонтировать просто обратившись к нему, например через `GetLogicalDrives()` - не работает чтоли?

Comment: Так это просто список доступных дисков, в функцию аргументы даже не передаются, как я к разделу обращусь?
P.S действbтельно, проглядел, в мане и вправду так написано, но только не помогает.

Comment: К разделу будет обращать ОС, которая сама и смонтирует том.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто: необходимо закрыть дескриптор ранее открытого тома. Т.е

> CloseHandle(hDisk);

И с этим я колупал мозги себе дней 10... А ведь на сайте микромягких всё написано:

> Изменение файловой системы тома
> 1.Откройте том.
> 2.Блокировка тома.
> 3.Отформатируйте том.
> 4.Отключите том.
> 5.Разблокируйте том.
> 6.Закройте дескриптор тома.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_dismount_volume

Answer (score 0):

Для монтирования томов используется функция `SetVolumeMountPointA()`, но ей нужен GUID тома, который необходимо будет получить до размонтирования. GUID с назначенными им буквами возвращает штатная утилита ком.строки **"mountvol"**, а программно его можно получить через `GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName()` или `GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPointW()`. Используя первую в связке с `FindNextVolume()`, я получаю у себя такой список GUID'ов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ага... Понял, щас, опробую. Но что в Студии, что в с++ Билдере просто вызов '''GetLogicalDrives()''' не особо хотел работать

Comment: Нифига. Я получаю GUID, запихиваю это в SetVolumeMountPointA() но раздел так же остаётся не активным.